# Is it possible to use the GMail "Call Phone" functionality on Android without Google Voice?

Tags: gmail, calls, google-voice

I'm outside the US so don't have access to Google Voice.

On the GMail web page, if you enable chat, you can see a "Call Phone" option which allows you to call land line phones from the web page.

Is there any way, to make use of this functionality to make outbound calls on Android?

Comment: I haven't been able to get it working in the browser, I'm assuming it and/or Flash doesn't have the necessary functionality.  Maybe a third-party client would work.

Comment: Yeah I have a feeling you have to install a plugin to get it working in the browser on the PC. I was thinking a 3rd party client too but can't find one.

Answer (score 1):

It may not be the ultimate approach -- but you probably could use [Clipboard Dialer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=se.grenangen.clipboarddialer) (left picture) to achieve this:

> This little tool enables you to extract all phone numbers from what ever text is in your clipboard. It will present a list of all numbers it finds giving you an easy way to call, SMS or create a new contact.

So as long as the numbers are visible on the screen, you could copy them to the clipboard -- and then let this tool kick in. Or, using the same principle: [CopyNDial](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rmitc.copyndial) (picture to the right):

> Dial from everywhere browser, message apps

[image: Clipboard Dialer] [image]