# Clickable Phone Numbers on a Wifi Only Tablet?

Tags: applications, calls

I have an Android tablet running KitKat.  It is a basic tablet that only connects over WiFi.  Apps like GrooveIP and Talkatone do allow me to make calls with it, but I have to copy and paste, or manually enter, every number, unless the number is in my Google Voice contacts.

On a smartphone, as an example, if I were to go into Google Maps, and look up a business, the phone number would be a clickable link.  It would automatically initiate a call.  On my tablet, any phone numbers I find anywhere - Google Maps, websites, even Google Contacts, are not clickable.

Are there any apps out there that can make the phone numbers on my tablet clickable?

Thanks!

Comment: Hm, what about e.g. [Clipboard Dialer](http://www.appbrain.com/app/se.grenangen.clipboarddialer)? For details, please see [my answer here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/27067/16575).

Comment: I have a Nexus 7. Unfortunately, according to the Play Store, Clipboard Dialer does not appear to be compatible.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Maybe [SnipFolio](http://www.appbrain.com/app/snipfolio-clipboard-manager/com.snipfolio), at least according to its description: *If you copy a phone number, SnipFolio lets you dial it with one click.*

Comment: Also not compatible. I can't figure out if the Nexus 7 is the problem, or if these apps just haven't been updated for KitKat yet.  Also, I haven't yet been able to figure out a way to even select a phone number in Google Maps.  Clicking, clicking and holding, clicking and dragging all do nothing.

Comment: Okay, I found an app called Copy and Dial (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fsalgado.copydial) which lives up to its name and seems to work on KitKat.  In a browser, I can highlight a phone number, hit Share, and send it to GrooveIP, but this is nearly as many clicks as just copying from the browser and pasting into GrooveIP.
It does not "linkify" the phone numbers in my browser.  And in Google Maps, I still, mysteriously, cannot even select a phone number I see on the screen.

Comment: I'm out of ideas then. Except that an alternative ROM might help: if you [google for "android linkify phone numbers"](https://www.google.com/search?q=android+linkify+phone+numbers), you see there's a specific `Linkify` class responsible for that, which has a method `gatherTelLinks()`. It could be this was "voided" by the ROM creator, and thus does nothing on your tablet. Of course, Google apps would most likely rely on that API code, which would explain things.